# Counter-examples for quasi-coherent, coherent, locally free and invertible sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves, quasicoherent-sheaves

I'm trying to find at least one counter-example for each of these concepts to feel more comfortable with understanding the ideas behind them but I cannot even get started :( Please help me find counter-examples for the following concepts:

1. A quasi-coherent sheaf that is not coherent
2. A coherent sheaf that is not locally free
3. A locally free sheaf that is not globally free
4. A locally free sheaf that is not invertible

I'm studying sheaves from Kempf's *Algebraic Varieties*. My main problem that prevents me from attacking the above questions is that I do not know how I can create new sheaves or modify old sheaves to make them have interesting properties. The only example of a sheaf I know is an algebraic variety with its structure sheaf (i.e. the $k$-algebra of regular functions over its open sets when it's considered as a space with functions). Kempf's definitions are so abstract for me and I would highly appreciate any glimpse of intuition or information that answers the above questions.

Comment: Do you know that quasi-coherent sheaves on an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ are the same thing as $A$-modules?

Comment: @loch  No. I do not know. Is that a theorem? I have just started learning about quasi-coherent and coherent sheaves from Chapter 5 of Kempf's Algebraic Varieties. So, it's probable that the fact you mentioned is standard and has been explained or mentioned in Kempf's book but I haven't understood it. I would appreciate it if you explained more.

Comment: This is explained in, e.g. Hartshorne or Vakil where you can look them up. But this only works for schemes (and not, e.g. complex analytic spaces) - so it's worth thinking about the question without using this (e.g. see Nicholas's answer), but at the very least this gives you plenty of examples in the scheme case.

Comment: @loch  Is it possible to solve this without schemes? Schemes aren't discussed in my AG course this semester. I really regret not having read Hartshorne at the beginning of the semester because the professor said it wasn't necessary to read it. Kempf has turned out to be really hard, specially for an undergraduate like me. :-/

Comment: Of course! see the posted answer. I just thought it's worth saying this so that you'll have plenty of examples (in the algebraic category) - once you've figured out how they work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the examples, I leave you as an exercise to check everything :-)

1) Take an uncoutable sum of $\mathcal O_X$.

2) Take a skyscraper sheaf, i.e $i_* \mathcal O_{p}$ where $i : p \to X$ is the inclusion.

3) This is less easy, the simplest example is the sheaf $\mathcal O(1)$ on $\Bbb P^1$.

4) Hint : a locally free sheaf of rank $r > 1$ can't be invertible.

Comment: Thanks. I will think more about your answer and I will write back to you if you don't mind. What is a skyscraper sheaf? Is $i: p \to X$ the injection of a point $p$ to a space with functions $X$? And $i_{*}$ is what exactly? It isn't the mapping that pull-backs regular functions on $X$ to $p$. Is it? Sorry for my stupid questions. :( I'm just having a really hard time with Kempf.

Comment: Of course take your time, and don't worry about stupid or not stupid questions. A skyscraper sheaf is $i_* \mathcal O_p$ where $\mathcal O_p$ is the structure sheaf of a point $p \in X$, and $i_*$ is the direct image. Concretely, $i_*\mathcal O_p(U) = 0$ if $p \notin U$ and $k$ else (where $k$ is your ground field).

Comment: Is $\mathcal{O}(1)$ the generator of the Picard group of $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: @stressedout-gone-  : yes ! (note that the generator is not unique, but both are not globally free and of course locally free )

Comment: I still cannot see why $3$ works. Is it because the only global functions on a project variety are constant? I think it's related to that but I cannot see how exactly.

Comment: @stressedout-gone- : It's a possible argument. You can show that if a locally sheaf of rank $1$ is globally free then it's isomorphic to $\mathcal O_X$, which should follows from the definition. Then, as you said the sections of $\mathcal O_X$ are just $k$ (your ground field) but sections of $\mathcal O_X(1)$ are $k[x,y]_1$ (linear homogenous polynomials), so it can't be globally free.